# Javascript - Redirect user to other page in X seconds

Tags: javascript

I try to redirect a user to another page after X seconds have passed, this is my attempt, but i get a error page and can't do anything:

[image]

```
 <span id="zeit"></span>

 <script>
     var timer=9;
     while (timer>0) {

        setTimeout(function(){
            timer = timer - 1;
            document.getElementById("zeit").innerHTML = timer;

        },1000);
    }

    window.location.href = "home";
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Solution:**

```
var timer=9;

setInterval(function(){
    timer = timer - 1;
    document.getElementById("zeit").innerHTML = timer;

    if (timer===0) window.location.href = "home";

},1000);
```

Comment: Home is a valid route to a page, and is not the page that I am on.

Comment: Then I get redirected instantly to the home page.

Comment: Your loop is infinite. `timer` never gets the chance to decrement.

Comment: How is it infinite? I run while timer is bigger than 0 and setTimeout will decrement 1 from timer every 1000ms

Comment: The timeout callback never gets to execute, as you are so busy looping. Asynchronous callback functions only get to execute if your currently running code stops. You are creating millions of timeouts.

Comment: Now I see, thank you!

Comment: Aww, i was about to post my solution, but someone locked the post ._. a pitty for everyone in the future who has the same problem.

Comment: The referenced Q&A should be enough to fix the issue.

Comment: I posted the solution in my question.